# Upload rvt then try to get model data

Tags: autodesk, revit-api, autodesk-model-derivative

https://gist.github.com/kenken64/b40ef906076018dc11aef1929b7e04a5

I am getting the following error after submit a job while checking status

200
application/json; charset=utf-8
b'{"type":"manifest","hasThumbnail":"false","status":"failed","progress":"complete","region":"US","urn":"dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6Zm9yZ2Vfc2FtcGxlMl9jNmVheHJpZmxxeXp2bWlybXQzMDZoc21hd2VodjlpZy9yYWMxLnJ2dA","version":"1.0","derivatives":[{"name":"LMV Bubble","hasThumbnail":"false","status":"failed","progress":"complete","messages":[{"type":"error","message":"Translation failure","code":"TranslationWorker-InternalFailure"}],"outputType":"svf"}]}'
check complete translate data returned status code 200.

Please help !

https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job
{"input": {"urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6Zm9yZ2Vfc2FtcGxlM19jNmVheHJpZmxxeXp2bWlybXQzMDZoc21hd2VodjlpZy9yYWMxLnJ2dA"}, "output": {"formats": [{"type": "svf", "views": ["2d", "3d"]}]}}
{'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Imp3dF9zeW1tZXRyaWNfa2V5In0.eyJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJDNmVheHJpRmxRWVp2bWlybXQzMDZIc01BV0VodjlJZyIsImV4cCI6MTUwMTUwMjc2NSwic2NvcGUiOlsiZGF0YTpyZWFkIiwiZGF0YTp3cml0ZSIsImRhdGE6Y3JlYXRlIiwiZGF0YTpzZWFyY2giLCJidWNrZXQ6Y3JlYXRlIiwiYnVja2V0OnJlYWQiLCJidWNrZXQ6dXBkYXRlIiwiYnVja2V0OmRlbGV0ZSJdLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2F1dG9kZXNrLmNvbS9hdWQvand0ZXhwNjAiLCJqdGkiOiJYMVh4R1l6UFZGVlpwZHlsR29MTmZKYjh4T2s1N0dEMDE0c2pNWWZhY1pzc1hDNmgwT0o2VTRIUWVhSEZHWGt4In0.janHAXhsbRtNQYZ9q-Pz7IsGZjF0Em_e_UoOurPr-4Q'}
201
application/json; charset=utf-8
b'{"result":"created","urn":"dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6Zm9yZ2Vfc2FtcGxlM19jNmVheHJpZmxxeXp2bWlybXQzMDZoc21hd2VodjlpZy9yYWMxLnJ2dA","acceptedJobs":{"output":{"formats":[{"type":"svf","views":["2d","3d"]}]}},"registerKeys":["2d8ddceb-9f0a-48e5-ae6e-53839cc6ded6"]}'
translate data returned status code 201.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have some wrong configurations while calling the Model Derivative Job API. Please change following line and try it again:

- `compressedUrn: true` to `compressedUrn: false`, since your model is a RVT file, it's not compressed.
- `rootFilename: "A5.iam"` to `rootFilename: "rac1.rvt"`.

P.S. Please call this API `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6Zm9yZ2Vfc2FtcGxlMl9jNmVheHJpZmxxeXp2bWlybXQzMDZoc21hd2VodjlpZy9yYWMxLnJ2dA/manifest` to delete the failure job before you resent the translation job.